# Create Pool middleware based on subdomain - Too many connections

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, middleware

The idea is, based on the subdomain ex. `tenant1.app.com` or `tenant2.app.com` the app connects to the corresponding database.

The database name is stored in the JWT during authentication.

**Is this the correct way to handle this use case?**

**middleware.js**

```js
let authenticationHandler = (req, res, next) => {
    
    let token = req.headers.authorization;

    jwt.verify(token, "tracer", (err, decoded) => {
        if (err) {
            res.status(401).send({message: "Access denied"});
        } else {
            req.decoded = decoded;     // <------ the token is passed to database middleware
            next();
        }
    });
};

let databaseHandler = (req, res, next) => {
    let database = req.decoded.database;

    let util = require("util");

    let pool = mysql.createPool({
        ...db,
        database: database,
    });

    pool.query = util.promisify(pool.query);

    req.pool = pool;             // <------ pool is passed to API

    next();
};

app.all("/api/*", middleware.authenticationHandler);
app.all("/api/*", middleware.databaseHandler);
```

**api.js**

```js
router.get("/api/products", async function (req, res, next) {
    try {
        let query = `select * from product;`;

        var rows = await req.pool.query(query);            // <------ the pool is used
        res.status(200).send(rows);
    } catch (err) {
        next(err);
    }
});
```

Comment: If this is a mysql error, then not really, since mysql cannot differentiate between connections from different subdomains. You can try to use max_usr_connections parameter for mysql user accounts, but this would mean that you have to create a separate mysql user account for each tenant and yiu have to be able to authenticate using the subdomain to mysql.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Let me ask another way, as I don't quite get how the pool works. Does calling `mysql.createPool()` each time create a new pool, meaning there are a thousand pools, or is it always the same one pool, where `pool.query()` draws connections from?

Comment: @Shadow Can you please check my submitted answer if it makes sense?

Comment: Can't comment on it, I only know mysql, not node.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up choosing the [conn.changeUser()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56142512/switch-database-in-a-connection-pool-in-nodejs-mysql) approach to achieve what I want.

The other option was [mysql.createPoolCluster()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20703579/whats-the-right-way-to-work-with-many-mysql-servers-from-node-js-simultaneously) which was a bit complicated, as I had to know the databases beforehand vs doing it on the fly.

How it works is...

1. Create a main pool in `server.js`.

```js
// One main pool is created on app initialization
let pool = mysql.createPool(db);
// That pool is passed in the database middleware
// which forwards a connection to a corresponding database for further use
app.all("/api/*", middleware.databaseHandler(pool));
```

2. Extract a connection from the pool in the middleware.

```js
let databaseHandler = (pool) => {
    return (req, res, next) => {
        // req.decoded comes from authenticationHandler
        let database = req.decoded.database;

        // Get a connection from the main pool in app.js
        pool.getConnection((err, conn) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                return;
            }
            // Change the database for the connection
            conn.changeUser({ database: database }, function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    return;
                }

                // Promisify for Node.js async/await.
                const query = util.promisify(conn.query).bind(conn);

                // Pass the modified query method down the chain as a property of req, avaiable via next()
                // connection.release() is called in the routes
                req.query = query;
                req.connection = conn;
                next();
            });
        });
    };
};
```

3. Use the connection in the API and release it afterwards.

```js
router.get("/api/products", async function (req, res, next) {
    try {
        let query = `select * from product;`;

        var rows = await req.query(query);
        res.status(200).send(rows);
    } catch (err) {
        next(err);
    } finally {
        req.connection.release();
    }
});
```

It seems to work well, if anyone spots a problem, please reply.